# Android Inflate Excetion when trying to add a fragment (android.vew.InflateException)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-inflate, inflate-exception

MainActivity.java
I followed this [tutorial][1]

and I got the Binary xml  inflate exception at line number 11.

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
            doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
            getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void doSearch(String query) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
    }

    private void getPlace(String query) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            onSearchRequested();
            break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle query) {
        CursorLoader cLoader = null;
        if (arg0 == 0)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(),
                    PlaceProvider.SEARCH_URI, null, null,
                    new String[] { query.getString("query") }, null);
        else if (arg0 == 1)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(),
                    PlaceProvider.DETAILS_URI, null, null,
                    new String[] { query.getString("query") }, null);
        return cLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
        showLocations(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void showLocations(Cursor c) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = null;
        LatLng position = null;
        mGoogleMap.clear();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            position = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(1)),
                    Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)));
            markerOptions.position(position);
            markerOptions.title(c.getString(0));
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        if (position != null) {
            CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLng(position);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >



 <fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Log cat:

> 07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error
>   inflating class fragment 07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-25 14:24:31.385:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-25 14:24:31.385:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-25 14:24:31.385:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3281): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   ... 11 more 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281): Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional
>   following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a
>   correct behavior: 07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):
>    07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at owt.a(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at oze.a(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at oze.a(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at oyg.a(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at oul.a(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at ouk.a(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   grv.onTransact(SourceFile:107) 07-25 14:24:31.385:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326) 07-25 14:24:31.385:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown
>   Source) 07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown
>   Source) 07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source) 07-25 14:24:31.385:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 07-25
>   14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown
>   Source) 07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>   07-25 14:24:31.385: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <!-- Protect the map component of the application using application signature -->
    <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Allows to receive map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
    Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use the Global Positioning System (GPS)
    to determine the device's location to within a very small area
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows to contact Google Serves -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- Google Maps Android API V2 requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Points to searchable activity -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

            <!-- Points to searchable meta data -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".PlaceProvider"
            android:authorities="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.PlaceProvider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- Specifies the Android API Key, which is obtained from Google API Console -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDbz3pVIwRjgoFDlzXtZeoqlb0nppSWg7Y" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which line you are asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

You are trying to create a `map fragment` which originated from `MapFragment` and by the time you inflate it here

```
SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
```

It wont create it because it is a `SupportMapFragment` not a `MapFragment` thus resulting to NPE

**solution:**

change it to `SupportMapFragment`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**EDIT:**

**problem:**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior
```

You are missing a permission in your manifest add this before `INTERNET` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I edited xml file as you suggested Im getting Inflate Exception